# Logarithmic distribution of profits among game winners

Tags: c#, sql, math, polynomial-math, logarithm

I have a gave, which, when it's finished, has a table of players and their scores. 
On the other hand i have a virtual pot of money that i want to distribute among these winners. I'm looking for a SQL query or piece of C# code to do so.

The descending sorted table looks like this:

```
UserId | Name | Score | Position | % of winnings | abs. winnings $
00579  | John | 754   | 1        |  ?            | 500 $    
98983  | Sam  | 733   | 2        |  ?            | ?    
29837  | Rick | 654   | 3        |  ?            | ?    <- there are 2 3rd places
21123  | Hank | 654   | 3        |  ?            | ?    <- there are 2 3rd places
99821  | Buck | 521   | 5        |  ?            | ?    <- there is no 4th, because of the 2 3rd places
92831  | Joe  | 439   | 6        |  ?            | ?    <- there are 2 6rd places 
99281  | Jack | 439   | 6        |  ?            | ?    <- there are 2 6rd places 
12345  | Hal  | 412   | 8        |  ?            | ?    
98112  | Mick | 381   | 9        |  ?            | ?    
and so on, until position 50 
98484  | Sue  | 142   | 50       |  ?            | 5 $
```

Be aware of the double 3rd and 6th places.

Now i want to distribute the total amount of (virtual) money ($ 10,000) among the first 50 positions. (It would be nice if the positions to distribute among (which is now 50) can be a variable).

The max and min amount (for nr 1 and nr 50) are fixed at 500 and 5.

Does anyone have a good idea for a SQL query or piece of C# code to fill the columns with **% of winnings**  and **absolute winnings $** correctly?

I prefer to have a distribution that looks a bit logarithmic like this: (which makes that the higher positions get relatively more than the lower ones).

```
.
|.
| .
|  .
|   .
|     .
|        .
|            .
|                  .
|                           .
```

Comment: Assuming that tied players make the same amount of money, this is impossible.  The problem is over-constrained.  For instance if there's a 49-way tie for first place you'll have to pay out $24505.  You probably will never have a 49-way tie, but you should be explicit then about what possibilities you care about and what possibilities you don't care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done SQL since 1994, but I like C# :-).  The following might suit, adjust parameters of `DistributeWinPot.DistributeWinPot(...)` as required:

```
private class DistributeWinPot {

    private static double[] GetWinAmounts(int[] psns, double TotWinAmounts, double HighWeight, double LowWeight) {
        double[] retval = new double[psns.Length];
        double fac = -Math.Log(HighWeight / LowWeight) / (psns.Length - 1), sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < psns.Length; i++) {
            sum += retval[i] = (i == 0 || psns[i] > psns[i - 1] ? HighWeight * Math.Exp(fac * (i - 1)) : retval[i - 1]);
        }
        double scaling = TotWinAmounts / sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < psns.Length; i++) {
            retval[i] *= scaling;
        }
        return retval;
    }

    public static void main(string[] args) {
        // set up dummy data, positions in an int array
        int[] psns = new int[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < psns.Length; i++) {
            psns[i] = i+1;
        }
        psns[3] = 3;
        psns[6] = 6;
        double[] WinAmounts = GetWinAmounts(psns, 10000, 500, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < psns.Length; i++) {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine((i + 1) + "," + psns[i] + "," + string.Format("{0:F2}", WinAmounts[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Output from that code was:

```
1,1,894.70
2,2,814.44
3,3,741.38
4,3,741.38
5,5,614.34
6,6,559.24
7,6,559.24
8,8,463.41
9,9,421.84
10,10,384.00
11,11,349.55
12,12,318.20
13,13,289.65
14,14,263.67
15,15,240.02
16,16,218.49
17,17,198.89
18,18,181.05
19,19,164.81
20,20,150.03
21,21,136.57
22,22,124.32
23,23,113.17
24,24,103.02
25,25,93.77
26,26,85.36
27,27,77.71
28,28,70.74
29,29,64.39
30,30,58.61
31,31,53.36
32,32,48.57
33,33,44.21
34,34,40.25
35,35,36.64
36,36,33.35
37,37,30.36
38,38,27.64
39,39,25.16
40,40,22.90
41,41,20.85
42,42,18.98
43,43,17.27
44,44,15.72
45,45,14.31
46,46,13.03
47,47,11.86
48,48,10.80
49,49,9.83
50,50,8.95
```

Comment: Looks interesting. But, i don't get the HighWeight, you input 500, but the highest win amount is 894.70?? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I have it 500 and 5, as you suggested in the question.  However, it needs to make the sum of the weights add up to 10000.  So it has to scale the initial results, that's what the second `for` loop is doing in `DistributeWinPot.DistributeWinPot(...)`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Im playing a bit with the input values now, and i see that when i provide a total win amount which would fit quite easily within the 50 winners, i always get a higher amount for my number 1 and number 2 always gets the max amount. That makes a bit less sense to me.

Comment: I don't understand your query.  Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Do you have an idea on how i could make the payout curve more or less steeper?

Comment: Just alter the HighWeight and LowWeight inputs.  Make the difference between them greater to make more steep, and make the difference between them lower to make less steep.

Comment: I want my high and low to be absolutely fixed. What i meant is to alter the curve a bit, so that i can distribute a bit more or less money among the higher positions. Is that some that is possible with this type of calculation?

Comment: It's always possible to add extra parameters to the equations to alter the exact shape, but the more complex the equations are, the less robust they tend to be.  However, my existing answer isn't over specified, and should always produce a distribution of winnings that makes sense.  Bear in mind the comment to your question which says *Assuming that tied players make the same amount of money, this is impossible*.  Although I think he was wrong, because I think my answer makes sense, with this sort of thing it is easy to specify things that are mathematically impossible.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This is not really my area of expertise, but with your help and example i think i can manage to create a suitable solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Then how about this?

```
Select userid, log(score),
   10000 * log(score) / 
      (Select Sum(log(score)) 
       From TableName
       Where score >=
            (Select Min(score) 
             from (Select top 50 score     
                   From TableName
                   Order By score desc) z)) 
From TableName
Order By score desc
```

Comment: I ran this query, but the results aren't really looking like what i was searching for. I have added a bit more to my example. Like the absolute amount of money for the 1st and 50th place. Which is fixed to 500 and 5.